# Nhibernate Session in WinForm C#

Tags: c#, winforms, session, nhibernate, mvp

I am  In a middle of a winForm Application and iam using MVP as Architecture 
and NHIBERNATE as ORM

All things are good so far , but now i want to use session container for my nh session to store and retrieve them .
in webform i use http request to store theme no problem but in Winform i am confused . the cose for webform is .

```
public class HttpSessionContainer : ISessionStorageContainer
{
    private string _sessionKey = "NhibernateSession";

    public ISession GetCurrentSession()
    {
        ISession nhSession = null;

        if (HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(_sessionKey))
            nhSession = (ISession)HttpContext.Current.Items[_sessionKey];

        return nhSession;
    }

    public void Store(ISession session)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(_sessionKey))
            HttpContext.Current.Items[_sessionKey] = session;
        else
            HttpContext.Current.Items.Add(_sessionKey, session);
    }
}
```

How to convert that code so i can store my session per Form .
thanks

Comment: I would recommend searching for information on the 'session-per-conversation' pattern. IMHO, this would be the ideal way of managing NHibernate sessions in a Windows Forms app that's using the MVP pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use static class to create Session Storage:

First create a SessionStorageFactory:

```
public static class SessionStorageFactory
{
    public static Dictionary<string, ISessionStorageContainer> _nhSessionStorageContainer = new Dictionary<string, ISessionStorageContainer>();
    public static ISessionStorageContainer GetStorageContainer(string key)
    {
        ISessionStorageContainer storageContainer = _nhSessionStorageContainer.ContainsKey(key) ? _nhSessionStorageContainer[key] : null;
        if (storageContainer == null)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current == null)
            {
                storageContainer = new ThreadSessionStorageContainer(key);
                _nhSessionStorageContainer.Add(key, storageContainer);
            }
            else
            {
                storageContainer = new HttpSessionContainer(key);
                _nhSessionStorageContainer.Add(key, storageContainer);
            }
        }
        return storageContainer;
    }
}
```

Then on your GetCurrentSession, you can access your SesssionStorage:

```
public ISession GetCurrentSession
    {
        get
        {
            ISessionStorageContainer sessionStorageContainer = SessionStorageFactory.GetStorageContainer(ConnectionName + ".SessionKey");
            ISession currentSession = sessionStorageContainer.GetCurrentSession();
            if (currentSession == null)
            {
                currentSession = GetNewSession();
                sessionStorageContainer.Store(currentSession);
            }
            return currentSession;
        }
    }

private ISession GetNewSession()
    {
        return GetSessionFactory().OpenSession();
    }
```